# How can I disable EJB on WildFly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

I have a set of applications which consist of Servlet API + CDI + JPA (with JTA), basically. I'm not using EJBs.

Is it possible to disable the EJB container in WildFly, making it more lightweight?

Comment: Well why not use a container meant for such like tomcat or run undertow and weld and hibernate standalone?

Comment: too much work to setup all of these in a standalone environment. I just wanted to change a config and disable it, but it seems not possible.

Comment: Sping-boot for you then.

Comment: Or use [Wildfly Swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/) - you can lighten up Wildfly from there.

Comment: You're not going to gain anything by doing this except more stuff to maintain. It's not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I won't put Spring to complicate my environment even more. Steve, just supposed the server would run faster but sounds like the EJB container is not invoked if it's not the case: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-performance/wildfly-performance-tuning

Answer (score -1):

well for starters you can start the Wildfly with standalone.xml instead of standalone-full.xml

not sure of the actual settings necessary for disabling EJB perhaps you can look around session beans  in the conf file

Comment: my understanding is that ejb is not enabled by default  http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-performance/wildfly-performance-tuning

Comment: You mean it is not used in the request context if it's not the case, right? If you deploy an EJB artifact it will surely work without additional configs.